# How I can show m2 price but pay for base price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

I have added number field to variation. So now I have three fields: `price`, `sale_price`, `base_price`

Example: I want `price` will be 6$\m2 and `base_price` 60$ and customer will add to cart 1 item and it costs `base_price`.

Why I need this? I sell bricks only base price where is 100 brick, but I have to let see people m2 price.

I used this code to add custom field:

```
// Admin: Add custom field in product variations options pricing
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options_pricing', 'add_variation_custom_option_pricing', 10, 3 );
function add_variation_custom_option_pricing( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ){

   woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'            => '_base_price['.$loop.']',
        'label'         => __("Base Price", "woocommerce") . ' (' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . ')',
        'class' => 'short wc_input_price',
        'data_type'     => 'price',
        'wrapper_class' => 'form-row form-row-first',
        'value'         => wc_format_localized_price( get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_base_price', true ) )
    ) );
}

// Admin: Save custom field value from product variations options pricing
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_custom_option_pricing', 10, 2 );
function save_variation_custom_option_pricing( $variation_id, $i ){
    if( isset($_POST['_base_price'][$i]) ){
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_base_price', wc_clean( wp_unslash( str_replace( ',', '.', $_POST['_base_price'][$i]) ) ) );
    }
}
```

and in product page I have this action hook:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' ); ?>
```

Comment: We expected you to provide in your question your own real code attempt. Please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Comment: I used that example to get field to variation tab, but confused about this woocommerce single product summary action hook...

Comment: The hook to affect displayed prices is `woocommerce_get_price_html` and [all related threads using this hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_get_price_html) … documented on [WooCommerce Github](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?q=woocommerce_get_price_html)

Comment: For displayed variation prices is `woocommerce_available_variation` and [all related threads using this hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_available_variation) … documented on [WooCommerce Github](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php#L364)